# Calling bluetooth commands freezes the coprocessor

Tags: arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, nucleo

I am trying to influence payload inside [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) advertisement beacons. My dev board is [NUCLEO WB16CC](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-wb15cc.html) based on a dual core [STM32WB15CC](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wb15cc.html).

Whenever I try to `aci_gap_update_adv_data(sizeof(manuf_data), manuf_data);` the program hangs between the `// LED` lines which I have added:

```
static void SendCmd(uint16_t opcode, uint8_t plen, void *param)
{
  // vorac
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(0x48000400, ((uint16_t)0x0020), 0);  // LED1
  pCmdBuffer->cmdserial.cmd.cmdcode = opcode;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(0x48000400, ((uint16_t)0x0001), 0);  // LED2

  pCmdBuffer->cmdserial.cmd.plen = plen;
  memcpy( pCmdBuffer->cmdserial.cmd.payload, param, plen );

  hciContext.io.Send(0,0);

  return;
}
```

`pCmdBuffer` is not null it actually points to `PLACE_IN_SECTION("MB_MEM1") ALIGN(4) static TL_CmdPacket_t BleCmdBuffer;`.

If that is changed to an ordinary global variable, the problem shifts down to the `hciContext.io.Send(0,0);` line.

I suspect some problem with the inter process communication but can't phantom where to look. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that the value in pCmdBuffer is not aligned, and the processor requires strict alignment.

Comment: There's the `ALIGN(4)` bit. But I am not sure how are all the memory sections aligned in respect to each other. (it expands to `__attribute((aligned(4))`)

Comment: The structure is aligned. But is the way you assign the pointer honouring that? Any casts there are dangerous

Comment: `pCmdBuffer` is generated and initialized by generated code by a proprietary IDE and I have not modified that. And then it crashes on a simple `uint16_t` **assignment**. There are quite a bit of `(name *)&var` casts generated. What modification do they need?